# Find out last value of a hive table using pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am querying a hive table to find out the last value of a unique column say `id`. I am doing like below

```
frame=sqlContext.sql("select max(id) from database.table")
```

when I do `frame.show()`

```
+------+
|   _c0|
+------+
|276308|
+------+
```

Now I want to get this as a `lastval` For this I am doing

```
frame1=frame.map(lambda row: [str(c) for c in row]).collect()

lastval =''.join(frame1[0][0])

print lastval

276308
```

I am getting the expected result but I am wondering  is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why are you stringifying the frame columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUYC.

Let's prepare some data:

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3]})
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pdf)
df.registerTempTable("tbl")
sqlContext.sql("select * from tbl").show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
+---+
```

Select "as is":

```
sqlContext.sql("select max(id) from tbl").show()
+-------+
|max(id)|
+-------+
|      3|
+-------+
```

Select "pretty" from Hive table:

```
sqlContext.sql("select max(id) as lastVal from tbl").show()
+-------+
|lastVal|
+-------+
|      3|
+-------+
```

Select "pretty" from Spark `df`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.select(F.max("id").alias("lastVal")).show()
+-------+
|lastVal|
+-------+
|      3|
+-------+
```

Should you be wishing to pass your data to pure Python for further use or analysis you may proceed as follows:

```
lv = sqlContext.sql("select max(id) as lastVal from tbl").collect()
print(lv[0]["lastVal"])
3

lv = df.select(F.max("id").alias("lastVal")).collect()
print(lv[0]["lastVal"])
3
```